# Trying to analyze clinical data using kaplan meier curve in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-extraction

I'm trying to plot kaplan meier curve using R Shiny. When I select "prior treatment" and "prior malignancy" it shows error quoted

```
Error:<text>:1:39: unexpected symbol
1: Surv(days_to_last_follow_up) ~  Prior Treatment
                                          ^
```

```
library(KMsurv)
library(readxl)
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(ranger)
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


data1 <- as.data.frame(read_xlsx("clinical_data.xlsx"))
str(data1)
# Set type to a factor
data1$`Vital Status` <- as.factor(data1$`Vital Status`)
data1$`Prior Treatment` <- as.factor(data1$`Prior Treatment`)
data1$`Prior Malignancy` <- as.factor(data1$`Prior Malignancy`)
n_total <- nrow(data1)


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Survival Analysis",
                   tabPanel( "Kaplan-Meier Survival Graph",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 h3("Survivial Graph"),
                                 # SelectInput gives you the option to choose the variable you want to observe in a dropdown list
                                 selectInput('sur_var', 'Factor of Survival', names(data1)[names(data1) != "patient" & names(data1) != "Vital Status" & names(data1) != "days_to_death" & names(data1) != "days_to_last_follow_up"]),
                                 # SliderInput, in this case, let you select the time point you want to observe
                                 sliderInput('xvalue', 'Survival Days = ',value=100, min=1, max=max(data1$days_to_death, na.rm = TRUE))
                               )
                               ,
                               mainPanel(
                                 h3(textOutput("caption")),plotOutput("plot1")
                                 , tableOutput("center")
                               )
                             )
                   )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  selectedData <- reactive({
    data1[, c(input$sur_var)]
  })
  
  # This is a caption that will show on top of the graph; the name will change based on which variable you choose
  output$caption <- renderText({
    paste("Survival Graph of", input$sur_var, sep="\n")
  })
  
  # Running the survival function
  runSur <- reactive({
    survfit(as.formula(paste("Surv(days_to_last_follow_up) ~ ",paste(input$sur_var))),data=data1)
  })
  
  # Plot the survival graph
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    plot(runSur(), 
         col=c("red","sky blue","green","purple","orange","yellow"), xlab="Days", ylab="S(t)")
    legend("bottomleft",cex=0.9,levels(selectedData()),legend = c(1:6), fill= c("red","sky blue","green","purple","orange","yellow"))
    abline(v=input$xvalue,col=1,lty=2)
  })
  
  # This table will give you the probability of survival for each class at a given time
  output$center <- renderTable({
    as.data.frame(summary(runSur(), times=input$xvalue )[c("surv", "time", "strata")])
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Output

[image]

Dataset

[image]

Comment: Have you run your survival analyses outside of the Shiny app successfully? The `Surv` function takes two necessary arguments - time and status - so I'm not sure if I would expect it to run as posted. If possible, can you share some of your data in a useable way to allow replication?

Comment: @AndyBaxter I've sent my dataset through mail. kindly check it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed-up shiny app running a survival analysis, with a few tweaks to above code:

```r
library(readxl)
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


data1 <- read_xlsx("clinical_data.xlsx")

# str(data1)
# Set type to a factor
data1 <- mutate(data1, across(where(is.character), as.factor))
n_total <- nrow(data1)

# Have a single time of event (censor or death)
data1 <- data1 |>
  mutate(
    day_obs = if_else(`Vital Status` == "Dead", days_to_death, days_to_last_follow_up),
    death = as.numeric(`Vital Status` == "Dead")
  ) |>
  as.data.frame()

# parts of app

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "Survival Analysis",
  tabPanel(
    "Kaplan-Meier Survival Graph",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h3("Survivial Graph"),
        # SelectInput gives you the option to choose the variable you want to observe in a dropdown list
        selectInput('sur_var', 'Factor of Survival', names(data1)[names(data1) != "patient" &
                                                                    names(data1) != "Vital Status" &
                                                                    names(data1) != "days_to_death" &
                                                                    names(data1) != "days_to_last_follow_up" &
                                                                    names(data1) != "day_obs" & names(data1) != "death"], ),
        # SliderInput, in this case, let you select the time point you want to observe
        sliderInput(
          'xvalue',
          'Survival Days = ',
          value = 100,
          min = 1,
          max = max(data1$day_obs, na.rm = TRUE)
        )
      )
      ,
      mainPanel(
        h3(textOutput("caption")),
        plotOutput("plot1")
        ,
        verbatimTextOutput("center")
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # This is a caption that will show on top of the graph; the name will change based on which variable you choose
  output$caption <- renderText({
    paste("Survival Graph of", input$sur_var, sep = "\n")
  })
  
  # Running the survival function
  runSur <- reactive({
    survfit(Surv(day_obs, death) ~ data1[[input$sur_var]], data = data1)
  })
  
  # Plot the survival graph
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(
      runSur(),
      col = c("red", "sky blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow"),
      xlab = "Days",
      ylab = "S(t)"
    )
    legend(
      "bottomleft",
      cex = 0.9,
      legend = levels(data1[[input$sur_var]]),
      fill = c("red", "sky blue", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow")
    )
    abline(v = input$xvalue,
           col = 1,
           lty = 2)
  })
  
  # This table will give you the probability of survival for each class at a given time
  output$center <- renderPrint({
    summary(runSur(), times = input$xvalue, extend = TRUE)
  })
  
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Output app]